# What type of event listener should i use in android?

Tags: android, listener, swipe, gesture-recognition

I have a 5x5 grid (I ve drawn a matrix in canvas). I ve arranged the textviews in the the grid
in the order of a array..ie (5X5 ) array. The thing is I want to change the values on of the text view when I swipe horizontally or vertically.

Say suppose I am using a touch movement on the screen continuously from [4][0] to [4][2] I want to modify the values of the textviews in those places.

Any ideas?

Comment: Easiest way, I think, is making the grid a `GestureView` and check in the `onTouch` if the current touch coordinate is within the `Rect` of a `TextView`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i didnt quite get you. Can you explain?

Comment: Make the grid a GestureOverlayView, with the textviews as children. Make your Activity implement `android.gesture.GestureOverlayView.OnGestureListener`. Add this line in onCreate: `((GestureOverlayView)this.findViewById(R.id.matrix)).addOnGestureListener(this);`

implement this method in activity: `public void onGesture(GestureOverlayView arg0, MotionEvent arg1)`

from here, check if the motionEvent is within the bounds of one of your textviews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code might help you:

```
public class MyClass extends Activity implements OnGestureListener{
    ArrayList<TextView> tvs = new ArrayList<TextView>();
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.mygrid);
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        GestureOverlayView gd = (GestureOverlayView)findViewById(R.id.gd);
        LinearLayout g = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mygrid);
        gd.addOnGestureListener(this);
        g.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
            g.addView(row);
            row.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams rowlp = (LayoutParams) row.getLayoutParams();
            rowlp.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            rowlp.weight = 1;
            rowlp.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            row.setLayoutParams(rowlp);
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                row.addView(tv);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) tv.getLayoutParams();
                lp.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                lp.width = 0;
                lp.weight = 1;
                tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
                tv.setText(String.valueOf(i * 5 + j));
                tv.setTag(String.valueOf(i * 5 + j));
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                tvs.add(tv);
                if ((i * 5 + j) % 2 == 0)
                    tv.setBackgroundColor(0xff888888);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isPointInsideView(float x, float y, View view){
        int location[] = new int[2];
        view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        int viewX = location[0];
        int viewY = location[1];

        //point is inside view bounds
        if(( x > viewX && x < (viewX + view.getWidth())) &&
                ( y > viewY && y < (viewY + view.getHeight()))){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onGesture(GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getRawX();
        float y = event.getRawY();
        for (TextView v : tvs) {
            if (isPointInsideView(x, y, v)) {
                v.setText("HERE");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onGestureCancelled(GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onGestureEnded(GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onGestureStarted(GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {

    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mygrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
```

Hope it helps.

Edit2: replace the methods above with these for highly increased performance:

```
private TextView getAbove(float x, float y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            if (isPointInsideView(x, y, tvs[i][j]))
                return tvs[i][j];
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onGesture(GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getRawX();
    float y = event.getRawY();
    if (last == null || !isPointInsideView(x, y, last)) {
        last = getAbove(x,y);
        draw();
    }   
}

private void draw() {
    if (last == null)
        return;
    last.setText("+");
}
private void reset() {
    last = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            tvs[i][j].setText(String.valueOf(i * 5 + j));
}

@Override
public void onGestureCancelled(GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {
    reset();
}
@Override
public void onGestureEnded(GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {
    reset();
}
@Override
public void onGestureStarted(GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {
    last = getAbove(event.getRawX(), event.getRawY());
    draw();
}

TextView[][] tvs = new TextView[5][5];
TextView last = null;
```

And make the `arraylist` into an `TextView[5][5]`

Comment: Thank you so much!! this is something that has been tearing me for so long!! :D ^_^!

Comment: @user1922235 You're welcome. Although even in the emulator this runs just fine, you should optimize the isPointInsideView method though, because now it runs through 25 TextViews. I suggest checking first if it has left the TextView it was above the last time the event occurred.

Comment: Yeah I did make the modifications!:DThanks !

Comment: @user1922235 See edit2 for increased performance, as i noticed some fields were skipped on the emulator if moving too fast across screen.

Comment: Hey thanks for the edit too! But the problem is I am not able to get the double tap event or long click method working (though the method is getting overriden ) I ve just put in a toast message in each of these methods n yet no result! Can you help?

Comment: I do not have much experience with doubletaplisteners, but this http://pastebin.com/YWwyLXbe might help you quite a bit.

Comment: Yeah saw that but i think that's again for the view type :( :/ Thanks :D

Comment: :I have this doubt regarding a piece of code i've written can you put up your mail id (If possible :)) so that i can ask you by mail directly?@Christiaan de Jong